# Fetch Api no regresa mi respuesta de mi APi

Tags: javascript, json, api, fetch

No estoy recibiendo respuesta de mi Api, al probarla con Postman funciona correctamente.

Me sale una leyenda de **Return value: undefined**

Alguien que me pueda ayudar, tambien adjunto mi metodo en JavaScript.

```js
    <script lang="JavaScript">
        function traerTexto() {
            var texto = document.getElementById('textArea').value;
            fetch('url', {
                method: 'POST',
                cache: 'no-cache',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'form-data',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    input: texto,
                })
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    debugger
                })
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Lo único raro que veo es el `'Content-Type': 'form-data'` , ya que no es valido porque estas enviado un json.  Para form-data seria `multipart/form-data ` y json `application/json `. Prueba cambiarlo

Comment: No se si este código es solo un ejemplo pero si lo tienes igual, osea literalmente `url` y `debugger`, no va a funcionar. El string `url` no es una url y `debugger` no está definida.

Comment: Aqui hay una guia super completa de como funciona Fetch incluso utilizando form-data: https://eldevsin.site/fetch-api-la-guia-completa-y-olvidarse-de-axios/